# Find all export function in so using frida

Tags: javascript, android, shared-libraries, frida

If I using `Module.findExportByName("libc.so", "fopen")` I can find `fopen` address in libc.so

How can I find all the function in "libc.so" using `frida`?

Answer (score 1):

In your Frida script, get the module object with `Process.getModuleByName` and then iterate through the `Exports` using `Module.enumerateExports` :

```js
// Get the "libc.so" module by name
var libcModule = Process.getModuleByName(targetLibrary);
if (libcModule) {
    console.log("[*] Found target library: " + libcModule.name);
    // Enumerate and log the exported functions
    libcModule.enumerateExports({
        onMatch: function (exp) {
            console.log("[+] Exported Function: " + exp.name);
        },
        onComplete: function () {
            console.log("[*] Enumeration complete.");
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log("[-] Target library not found: " + targetLibrary);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to get all exports from the `.so` module you can use `frida+objection` with this command:
`objection -g YourApplicationName or com.package.name explore`

`memory list exports libc.so`